# Bluetooth receiver not listed in list-sinks even though paired

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, a2dp

My Bluetooth receiver says its paired and connected to my Ubuntu 14.04 Chromebook but does not get listed as an out device in pulseaudio volume control.

When I try:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

My Bluetooth device does not show up. If I look at my Bluetooth device manager I see the music receiver is there and can see the activity.

What am I missing?

FYI

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

results in

```
41
```

and

```
sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 00:12:6F:41:52:EE
```

results in:

```
Release
New device (/org/bluez/519/hci0/dev_00_12_6F_41_52_EE)
```

Comment: have you found a solution or a work around?